# How to make reactions appear instantly - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm developing a help command with reactions, but all reactions take a while to show up and I was getting a reference with another bot, and in it the reactions show up almost instantly

Can someone help me?

My code:

```
    message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
        msg.react('⭐')
        msg.react('')
        msg.react('')
        msg.react('')

        const diversao = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
        const informacoes = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⭐' && user.id === message.author.id;
        const staff = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
        const economia = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;

        const diversaoL = msg.createReactionCollector(diversao);
        const staffL = msg.createReactionCollector(staff);
        const informacoesL = msg.createReactionCollector(informacoes);
        const economiaL = msg.createReactionCollector(economia);

        informacoesL.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rate limit by Discord so unfortunately there's not much you can do about it. You may however want to check out [Discord's new buttons feature](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500012250861-Bots-Buttons), which I believe would be instant.